# What does the condition "Unattended" mean?

Tags: dnd-4e

I am building a monk on the D&D Insider Character builder and the level 1 encounter power Eagle Claw Strike says:

> Hit: 2d8 Dexterity modifier damage, and the target takes a penalty to AC equal to your Strength modifier until the end of your next turn. Against an unattended object, this attack deals 2d8 extra damage.

Considering it's an unattended *object* does that mean any object that is not being manipulated by a creature? Like a door, crate, table, etc that is not currently being interacted with?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term **unattended** has one definition tucked away in the rules. *Pick up an item*, an action defined under *Manipulating objects* in the Rules Compendium (p244), contains this bullet point:

> - **Unattended:** A creature can't use this action to pick up an item in an enemy's space, unless the creature is helpless. Similarly, the creature can't use this action to pick up an item that another creature is holding or an item on another creature's person, unless that other creature is willing or helpless.

Thus, **Unattended** means:

> - The object is not in an enemy's space, unless the creature is helpless.
> - The object is not being held by a creature, nor is it on another creature's person, unless that creature is willing or helpless.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I searched it in the online compendium, but came up empty.